# Object Create polyfill

Tags: javascript, object

For this task, I need to implement the `Object.create` polyfill.

*Object.create - Creates and returns a new object whose prototype is the first argument passed to the function. If a second argument is passed, sets it as properties for the new object.*

The function must take two parameters:

**prototype (required)** - An object, or null (but not undefined), which will be the prototype for the created object.

**properties (optional)** - an argument that will set properties for the new object (will be passed to `Object.defineProperties`).

If there are no function parameters or prototype is NOT an object or null, then a *`TypeError`* must be thrown.

As a result, `Object.create` will return the created object with the [[Prototype]] internal property set to the value passed in the prototype argument. If properties are passed and is NOT undefined, then `Object.defineProperties (obj, properties)` will be called, where obj is the object to be returned from `Object.create`.

Example:

```
const A = {
  objectName: 'Object A',
  getObjectName: function() {
    return `This is ${this.objectName}!`;
  },
};

const B = Object.create(A, {
  objectName: {
    value: 'Object B',
  },
});

A.getObjectName(); // This is Object A!
B.getObjectName(); // This is Object B!

A.hasOwnProperty('getObjectName'); // true
A.hasOwnProperty('objectName'); // true

B.hasOwnProperty('getObjectName'); // false
B.hasOwnProperty('objectName'); // true
```

The solution to the task must be written in this function:

```
Object.create = function(proto, propertiesObject) {
  //code here
}
```

**My try:**

```
Object.create = function(proto, propertiesObject) {
     if (typeof proto !== 'object' && typeof proto !== 'function') {
            throw new TypeError();
        } else if (proto === null) {
            return {};
        }
 
        if (typeof propertiesObject != 'undefined') return
 
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = proto;
 
        return new F();
};
```

Only 2 points fail on the test (where there are crosses):

```
✕ must return an empty object when called with a null argument (10ms)
✓ `prototype` argument works as expected (1ms)
✕ the `properties` argument works as expected (1ms)
✓ object A must be the prototype of object B (1ms)
✓ objects A and B must be different (1ms)
✓ without arguments there must be a TypeError (2ms)
✓ if the first parameter is not an object or null then there must be a TypeError (2ms)
```

Help me please do it right

Comment: `Object.create(null)` should return an object with no prototype. `{}` has the prototype `Object`. --- Ah I just noticed that your test says otherwise.

Comment: @evolutionxbox How do I deal with these two failed items in the test?

Comment: What does the second failing test mean by “works as expected”? It’s not a very helpful message

Comment: @evolutionxbox means that it works correctly

Comment: I understand that, but I’m trying to point out that “works correctly” isn’t defined.